# I have a reference to a class that is null

Tags: java, class, model-view-controller

I'm trying to execute a method in another class but my reference is null.

I have a Main calculator class that begins like so:

```
public class Calculator {

public static void main( String[] args ) {

    // create new model, view and controller
    Model theModel = new Model();
    View theView = new View();
    Controller theController = new Controller( theModel, theView );

    /* start it up */
    theView.CalcView();
```

Inside the **view class**, I have buttons that I create as such registering the controller as the listener:

```
    btnZero = new JButton( "0" );
    btnZero.addActionListener( new Controller() );
    btnZero.setBounds( 167, 174, 86, 23 );
    frame.getContentPane().add( btnZero );
```

Also inside the **view class** I capture keys pressed:

```
    private void keyPressed( KeyEvent e, Controller controller ) {
    controller.keyPressed( e );
}
```

My current objective is to execute a method in the **view class** from the **controller class** with a keystroke **view.toggleBorder( '1', true );**:

```
    public void keyPressed( KeyEvent e ) {
    char key = e.getKeyChar();

    switch ( key ) {
    case '1':
    System.out.println( "1" );
    view.toggleBorder( '1', true );
    break;
```

The Controller constructor:

```
    public Controller( Model model, View view ) {
    this.model = model;
    this.view = view;

}
```

But I also have a no argument constructor that I had to make when registering the controller as the listener as you see in the button code above. The issue is, when it comes to **view.toggleBorder..**, the reference to **view** is null so it throws a null pointer exception. I think there is a problem with the harmony of my classes but I cannot find where there might be problems. This code is fragmented I apologize. You can view the source files on [GitHub](https://github.com/KiloJKilo/Calculator/tree/master/Calculator/src/com/kevinjkahl/calculator)

Comment: Where is the null pointer exception thrown?

Comment: @beresfordt  view.toggleBorder( '1', true ); inside the controller class

Comment: Your view needs a reference to he controller which is controlling it. The instance that you register to your button has no knowledge of either the view or model. Create a method in view called setController, which you MUST call after you construct your first controller

Comment: Don't use key listener, use key bindings. I hope your not registering a mouse listener against the button

Comment: The Controller in main is not being used and this is the only Controller constructed with a view and model being passed to it. On running the application the no arg constructor for controller is called 38 times; this does not seem right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your View class when you initialize all your buttons and components, you run `btnOne.addActionListener( new Controller() );` for every button. The problem with this is that you are creating a new instance of controller for every button, none of which have instances to your model or view objects.

The other problem you have here is that you have two classes, and each need a fully functional instance of the other class to become fully functional.

One way you can solve this is by making a static instance variable of Controller in your Calculator class, and add methods to Controller to give View and Model too it. Only add your listeners to your buttons with your static instance, and only add the listeners after your Controller has an instance of View.

Comment: Yes, I had a hunch that there was an issue with creating a new instance of controller for every button. I'm still learning and I haven't put  together how to call one listener that encomposes all the buttons.

Comment: You have to think of it in terms of objects. You created a new object for every button, but should be passing the same object to every button.

Comment: do you see an issue with the order for which things are being created? When I step into this using debugger I see that when the view is created View theView = new View(), the model and controller are null inside the view. When the object is created, it executes the initialization of the frame under the initialize() function in the view class. So now, when the theController = newController (model, view) gets created, the detail for view are screwed up. further down CalcView executes. this doesn't seem right.

Comment: Im telling you the way you have it set up won't work without a ton of messy work arounds and bad practices. You are creating objects that depend on things that aren't created yet and can't be created yet because they depend on the thing you are trying to create.

Comment: Ok, so I'm creating the view object with references to controller which has not been created yet? I need to add the listening aspect after the three objects are fully created? - from the controller?

Comment: Yes, yes, no. You are right in saying that you need to make the buttons listen to the controller after its already been created, but you fail to use OOP as it was truely intended. Java is not ment to run as a net, but rather as a tree, with classes that manage smaller classes. Where the listening aspect should really be added is in the Calculator class. Or within the Controller class, but called by the Calculator.

Comment: i've added a new branch called new_controller to github where i'm trying to implement the first half of what you say. Am I going in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Your view needs a reference to he controller which is controlling it. The instance that you register to your button has no knowledge of either the view or model.

Create a method in view called setController, which you MUST call after you construct the controller

```
// create new model, view and controller
Model theModel = new Model();
View theView = new View();
Controller theController = new Controller( theModel, theView );

 theView.setController(theController);
```

You could do thus within the controllers constructor instead if you wished